# Initialising an array that's already initialised (Angular)?

Tags: angular, typescript, web

I am copying the following demo found here:

https://www.tutsmake.com/angular-12-export-data-to-excel-example/?ref=morioh.com&utm_source=morioh.com

The example uses an array in the component type script

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'excel';
 

  ngOnInit() {

    this.sales = [
      { brand: 'Apple', lastYearSale: '51%', thisYearSale: '40%', lastYearProfit: '$54,406.00', thisYearProfit: '$43,342' },
      { brand: 'Samsung', lastYearSale: '83%', thisYearSale: '96%', lastYearProfit: '$423,132', thisYearProfit: '$312,122' },
      { brand: 'Microsoft', lastYearSale: '38%', thisYearSale: '5%', lastYearProfit: '$12,321', thisYearProfit: '$8,500' },
      { brand: 'Philips', lastYearSale: '49%', thisYearSale: '22%', lastYearProfit: '$745,232', thisYearProfit: '$650,323,' },
      { brand: 'Song', lastYearSale: '17%', thisYearSale: '79%', lastYearProfit: '$643,242', thisYearProfit: '500,332' },
      { brand: 'LG', lastYearSale: '52%', thisYearSale: ' 65%', lastYearProfit: '$421,132', thisYearProfit: '$150,005' },
      { brand: 'Sharp', lastYearSale: '82%', thisYearSale: '12%', lastYearProfit: '$131,211', thisYearProfit: '$100,214' },
      { brand: 'Panasonic', lastYearSale: '44%', thisYearSale: '45%', lastYearProfit: '$66,442', thisYearProfit: '$53,322' },
      { brand: 'HTC', lastYearSale: '90%', thisYearSale: '56%', lastYearProfit: '$765,442', thisYearProfit: '$296,232' },
      { brand: 'Toshiba', lastYearSale: '75%', thisYearSale: '54%', lastYearProfit: '$21,212', thisYearProfit: '$12,533' }
  ];
   
}
```

However sales in  this.sales is highlighted with the following error.

`Property 'sales' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'`

From searching the problem online it seems I might need to initialise sales, but is it not initialised within the code already?

Comment: You don't  have `sales` initialized. under `title` just put `sales: any = [];` Ideally you'd want a strongly type instead of `any` but this should be enough remove the error you have for that tutorial

Comment: Thank you, I wont admit how long I was stuck on this.

Answer (score 1):

Because it does not. Add it as sa property

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'excel';
  sales:[]=[]; // this will do the trick

  ngOnInit() {

    this.sales = [ ....
```